# Save web page as pdf with links?

Tags: pdf, links

Is there a way to save a web page as PDF on the Macintosh so that I can click on the links within the page to take me to the appropriate web page?

Comment: Safari, Chrome, Firefox ?

Answer (score 1):

I found out that in Safari there's a Export PDF but print to PDF also works in Safari.  However it seems that Print to PDF does not retain links in Chrome.